# Why doesn't my first person character stand on the bridge when stepping on it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a simple project in Unity 5 and I have added a bridge from 3Ds Max to my scene which is a bridge. The problem is that it does not appear as a real object! I mean that a first person character must walk on the bridge but whenever I test it, it goes through the object. It looks like the bridge does not exist at all.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Collider` to your Bridge 3D model then test it with your `Character Controller`. Without Collider Unity can't tell when you bump into an object or when you are on top of it.

Select the 3D Bridge, click the **Add Component** button then type in `Box Collider`. Adjust the `Box Collider` to fit the 3D Bridge. You can always use multiple `Box Colliders` if needed.